# c# mvc 5, facebook login - How to ask extra user info after initial login

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-oauth, katana

Our website has FB login, implemented using libraries from Katana project. When configuring FB authentication, I set the required permission fields to minimal (email, firstname, lastname). This is the standard account registration in our website and works fine.

However we have a second type of users in the website and their account requires more data from facebook, related to their facebook page(s), like cover picture, user posts, page description, etc. If a user decides to change his account type to the second one, we would like to fetch some more information from facebook.

Can I somehow trigger a re-authorization FB popup with different set of permission fields? The user is logged in with FB at this point, we just need more permissions, something like a re-login with different FacebookAuthenticationOptions configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking, I solved my problem by using Facebook javascript API to re-login with different permissions set. You can initialize FB Api to allow subsequent interactions:

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '[APP_ID_HERE]',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.9',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Notice the status, cookie, and oauth parameters. Not sure if all are needed but they will make the browser to store an authorization token when you re-login with extra permissions and then you can fetch data easily via FB graph api. This way I'm getting a json object with all data I need and then I post that json to my website via an ajax request. That's how facebook data gets into my application.

If someone has a better solution, I would be happy to see it.